# MySQL: Calculate standard deviation from value / frequency pairs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in a MySQL database as below - is it possible to calculate the standard deviation of the population in a single query? I can find ways to calculate the standard deviation of a column of data (i.e. just the frequency), what I need is the standard deviation of the set [1080, 1090, 1090, 1090 ... , 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, ... ] etc?

```
Time    Frequency
-----------------
1080    1
1090    10
2000    100
2010    50
2020    5
2030    3
```

Comment: This means that `2000` occurs 100 times in your population or sample; correct? Also, is this your entire population or a sample? It makes a difference in terms of what formula you use for the standard deviation. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Uncorrected_sample_standard_deviation)

Comment: Good question :) Yes you are correct, 2000 would appear 100 times, 2010 would appear 50 times etc. The data represents the population, not a sample.

Comment: So you want the standard deviation of the time; correct?

Comment: Yes, standard deviation of the population of times.

Comment: Is `Time` some kind of seconds or minutes value from some "zero" time? It doesn't appear to be an actually time of day. If I'm correct, that simplifies the problem considerably.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. The 'time' is in 'minutes from zero' (not the time on a clock) and for my purposes the units don't matter - it's just the integer value I'm interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two choices.  Expand the data to have multiple rows for each value and use `std_pop()`.  Alternatively, implement the calculation yourself.

The standard deviation is basically the square root of the sum of the values minus the average squared.  If I have the calculation right, you can do it as:

```
select sqrt(sum(tf.frequency * power(tf.time - tfavg.avgtime, 2.0)) / tfavg.cnt)
from tf cross join
     (select sum(time*frequency) / sum(frequency) as avgtime,
             sum(frequency) as cnt
      from tf
     ) tfavg;
```

Comment: I believe `cnt` should be `SUM(frequency)` to give the total population count. The denominators of the average and the population standard deviation should be the same.

Comment: Good answer. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a41d/1/0) and some evidence the math is correct: [This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39ea39/2/0) shows that the table contains the correct population set. [This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39ea39/4) shows the population standard deviation that you get from the population. As you can see, they're the same.